# Is it allowed to "insult yourself"?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question, policy

The original poster of this question "insulted himself/herself".
I'm not sure if it's allowed.
Can you tell me?
[A super smart rebus](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30844/a-smart-super-rebus)

Answer (score 7):

It's quite common in everyday English (and many other languages/cultures) to do this (with some words, like 'idiot' and 'moron'; there are probably words which are off-limits even in this context).

I see no reason why it should be disallowed on Puzzling Stack Exchange. We have a [Code of Conduct](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/conduct) but it mainly is about interaction with other people, not 'interacting' with yourself.